# How to get latitude and longitude from user with Form API

Tags: 6, views, forms, google-maps

I want to create a database-driven website with Drupal 6 to gather some information from users that is related to the location; I want to create a form (and I don't want to use Webforms, or CCK) to get some data from users, and to get coordinates by creating a point on a map (by Openlayers or Gmap API), and then saving those data in a database table. I also want to integrate it with Views module so i can make a query from data.

Answer (score 2):

I'm quite happy with the [Geolocation Field](http://drupal.org/project/geolocation) module for Drupal 7. It allows you to put a field on any entity (user or node or whatever) that uses a map. It also has an html5 module to collect the information. Great stuff, actively maintained.

Comment: Too bad it's not back ported to drupal-6. It looks very interesting!

Answer (score 1):

There is already a module that is doing the form part, see [HTML5 user geolocation](https://www.drupal.org/project/html5_user_geolocation).

Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> ... a simple module to let users store their location on the edit account page. It uses [HTML5’s geolocation API](http://www.w3.org/TR/geolocation-API/) and stores latitude and longitude. How you use that data is up to other modules.
>
> It [was used on Drupal.org](http://drupal.org/community-initiatives/redesign) when Drupal.org used Drupal 6.
>
> For more than users or for a Drupal 7 version, try [Geolocation Field](http://drupal.org/project/geolocation) with the Geolocation HTML5 widget. Now that it is on Drupal 7, Drupal.org uses the Geolocation Field for this feature.

Comment: thank you for your reply but I want to know how to use map in my custom form

Comment: Then check out how that module is doing it.

Answer (score 0):

```
function geo_get_coords($address) {
  $map_key = "put your google map key";
  $url = sprintf('http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?&q=%s&output=csv&key=%s',rawurlencode($address),$map_key);

  if ($result = file_get_contents($url)) {
    $result_parts = explode(',',$result);

    if($result_parts[0] != 200) {
      return FALSE;
    }

    $coords['lat'] = $result_parts[2];
    $coords['lon'] = $result_parts[3];
  }

  return $coords;
}
```